# Magento group upsell products by category

Tags: magento-1.8, category, products, group

i'm a newbie to magento, default using `$this->getItemCollection()->getItems()` (upsell.phtml) displaying all up selling products.

I'm wondering how to group these results by its category.

Example, i have 4 up sell products,

```
3 Products from category A,

1 Product from category B
```

On view i need to display like this,

```
Category A,

Product 1 | product 2 | Product 3

Category B,

Product 4
```

So far created a module, it's structure below,

```
local
   Fugen
     Accessories
        etc
          config.php
        Model
          Observer.php
```

My module's config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fugen_Accessories>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Fugen_Accessories>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_upsell>
                <observers>
                    <Fugen_Accessories>
                        <class>Fugen_Accessories/observer</class>
                        <method>updateUpsells</method>
                    </Fugen_Accessories>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_upsell>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

My Observer.php

```
class Fugen_Accessories
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      // leave empty
    }

    public function updateUpsells(Varien_Event_Observer $oObserver)
    {
        $iCurrentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
        $oUpsellCollection = $oObserver->getCollection();
        foreach ($oUpsellCollection->getItems() as $key => $oUpsellProduct) {
            $aCategoriesIds = $oUpsellProduct->getCategoryIds();
            if (!in_array($iCurrentCategory, $aCategoriesIds)) {
                $oUpsellCollection->removeItemByKey($key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check question. Please approved the edit.It make more suitable  question.

Comment: @Amit Bera what's wrong with question ? can you be bit clear ?

Comment: no issue.this title make more suitable question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell::_prepareData()`.

It throws event with upsell products collection.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_upsell', array(
    'product'       => $product,
    'collection'    => $this->_itemCollection,
    'limit'         => $this->getItemLimit()
));
```

So we can create observer, attach to `catalog_product_upsell` event and change upsell products collection as we wish.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fugen_Accessories>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Fugen_Accessories>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <fugen_accessories>
                <class>Fugen_Accessories_Model</class>
            </fugen_accessories>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_upsell>
                <observers>
                    <fugen_accessories>
                        <class>fugen_accessories/observer</class>
                        <method>updateUpsells</method>
                    </fugen_accessories>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_upsell>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

In observer create method

```
class Fugen_Accessories_Model_Observer
{
    public function updateUpsells(Varien_Event_Observer $oObserver)
    {
        $iCurrentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
        $oUpsellCollection = $oObserver->getCollection();
        foreach ($oUpsellCollection->getItems() as $key => $oUpsellProduct) {
            $aCategoriesIds = $oUpsellProduct->getCategoryIds();
            if (!in_array($iCurrentCategory, $aCategoriesIds)) {
                $oUpsellCollection->removeItemByKey($key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also do not forget to add module initialization config in `app/etc/modules`

Fugen_Accessories.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fugen_Accessories>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog/>
            </depends>
        </Fugen_Accessories>
     </modules>
</config>
```

**Pay attention** solution was not tested.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I Made a module and followed your steps, and i can see my new module Enabled under system-> advanced -> Disable modules output. But no change in frontend ??

Comment: Are you sure that code from observer is executed?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have mentioned my module files in above question. Can you have plz have a look.

Comment: Update answer plz take a look.

Comment: Is there anything needs to be done on frontend file i.e, upsell.phtml because i'm not getting any changes in frontend. I cleared cache and did all possible things. Any idea where its wrong ?

Comment: In `updateUpsells` put some echo or var_dump to check if code is executed.

Comment: Yes observer code is executing properly. On **echo $iCurrentCategory** i'm getting categoryid **26** but on echo **$oUpsellCollection = $oObserver->getCollection();** is **empty**